# Designing a temperature feedback loop in Proteus

Tags: atmega, feedback, proteus

I am writing a term paper on the topic "Modeling of an Artificial Blood Circulation Apparatus". The task is to design a control unit based on the ATmega128 microcontroller in Proteus software. It was decided to implement two feedback loops: one regulates the mean blood pressure, and the other regulates blood temperature. Since there is no concept of the "environment" in the software, I had to use a second microcontroller to emulate the organism.
[image: Current state of model]
Pressure regulation is implemented as follows: the artificial blood circulation apparatus (AICA) controls the pump rotor, thereby regulating the blood flow rate. The blood flow rate is "felt" by the "organism" (the second microcontroller) by reading pulses from the motor encoder. Then, the motor rotation frequency is formulaically converted into a blood pressure value, and this value is transmitted to the first microcontroller (AICA control unit) using a smoothed PWM signal, simulating the operation of a pressure sensor.

The question is as follows: how to now implement a temperature regulation system? I tried using the DS1631 thermostat for this purpose, but the current temperature in Proteus can only be set manually, whereas I need programmatic control.
[image: DS1631 model in Proteus]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I tried using the DS1631 thermostat for this purpose, but the current
> temperature in Proteus can only be set manually, whereas I need
> programmatic control.*

Use an ADC fed by a voltage source to emulate a variable temperature digital input into your MCU. The voltage source can be from a DAC if you wish to maintain full control of the process from one MCU to the other.

Or, if your MCUs have analogue inputs and digital outputs, use those. 1 volt can represent whatever temperature you want!!

Comment: Yes, I also thought about that. However, it seemed to me that there is a way that is closer to the real device. After all, I could have used a similar approach for pressure regulation.

Comment: @MaksimPonomarenko "closer to the real device" <-- I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Yeah, i'm sorry, my bad for miscommunication. My goal is to create a model that accurately reflects the physical processes and components used in medical equipment. I get that your approach is dictated by limitations of software. But, I want the model to get closer to simulating the operation of a real blood circulation apparatus not just theoretically, but practically. That's why I'm asking if there is a method closer to the real device.

Comment: My approach is dictated by this being an EE site, me being an EE and me not having a clue about the physical processes you allude to. @MaksimPonomarenko